# Outlook interoperability: attach string to message

Tags: .net, email, outlook, email-attachments

I want to add a message to a .net created email (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem).

However, I don't have a file, only a string.
[This method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290846.aspx) would then not work.

Is it possible to attach a string as an attachment?

Comment: What is the content & purpose of the message? **Content:** Binary, XML, etc.? **Purpose:** Metadata, tracking, etc.?

Comment: Content: XML or plain text. Purpose: well, to be read by the recipient.